# Inline initialize objects of different types in array of an interface type

Tags: interface, typescript, initialization

Is it possible to inline initialize an array of the interface type `IFooFace` with different specific implementations? Or is it not possible and I have to initialize my objects before the array and then just pass them in?

This is how I can do it in C#:

```
public interface IFooFace
{
    int Id { get; }
}

public class Bar : IFooFace
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Zar : IFooFace
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MegaName { get; set; }
}

internal class Program
{
    public static IFooFace[] Data =
    {
        new Bar
        {
            Id = 0,
            Name = "first"
        },
        new Zar
        {
            Id = 1,
            MegaName = "meeeega"
        }
    };
}
```

And this is what I tried in TypeScript:

```
export interface IFooFace {
  id: number;   
}

export class Bar implements IFooFace {
    public id: number; 
    public name: string;
    // a lot of more properties
}

export class Zar implements IFooFace {
    public id: number; 
    public megaName: string;
    // a lot of more properties 
}

var Data : IFooFace[] =  [
    // how to initialize my objects here? like in C#?

    // this won't work:

    // new Bar(){
    //     id: 0,
    //     name: "first"
    // },
    // new Zar() {
    //     id: 1,
    //     megaName: "meeeeega"
    // }



    // this also doesn't work:
    // {
    //     id: 0,
    //     name: "first"
    // },
    //  {
    //     id: 1,
    //     megaName: "meeeeega"
    // }    
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, TypeScript [does not have object initializers](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3895). @RyanCavanaugh shows [possible solution](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3895#issuecomment-122046396) in TS:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(initializers: ...) { ... }
}

var x = new MyClass({field1: 'asd', 'field2: 'fgh' });
```

Comment: wow... I didn't even realize that there aren't any object initializers at all - I always thought it worked when you just do `var bla : Foo { ...} ` but if you look with `instance of` later it's not even an instance of `Foo` but instead of `object`...I must say I'm kinda disappointed... thanks anyway.